# MVC Response.Redirect not working with question mark

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, response.redirect

I am trying to redirect to another page from a controller, the code is:

```
Response.Redirect("http://server1:8080/amj/servlet/inv/template/print.html?txt=ABC");
```

But the redirect is done to this url:

```
http://server1:8080/amj/servlet/inv/txt/ABC/template/print.html
```

As you can see, it puts the txt=ABC in the middle of string...

If I try with the url without question mark, it works fine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Carlos.

Comment: Why are you using `Response.Redirect` in an MVC application where you have appropriate ActionResults at your disposalthat your controller actions should be returning?

Comment: The URL is the URL. If it changes along the way, that means there's some other redirect in play. There's not enough information here to diagnose that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below. The controller's `ActionResult` can return `Content` type which contains the link for your redirect.

```
public ActionResult RedirectPage(long param)
{
     string url = "http://server1:8080/amj/servlet/inv/template/print.html?id=" + param;
     return Content("<html><script>window.location.href = '" + url + "';</script></html>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query string parameters are matching one of the routes in your routing setup.

You can get around this for a specific page/route by using [routes.IgnoreRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) inside your RegisterRoutes method.

Another option would be to not use Response.Redirect and instead use the Controller/Action route model. This would be the preferred approach and you can read more about why in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix.aspx) article.